# How to make my laravel app.js work aftre that i've imported fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

when I added that FullCalendar cdns mu app.js stopped from working... Means all those bootstrap js functionalities are not working anymore (modal isn't showing, navbar is no longer working in small screans...). Here are the FullCalendar CDNS :

```
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

And the app.js importation :

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: did you check for Console errors in the browser?

Comment: the browser shows nothing in the console

Comment: Did you `require('./bootstrap');` in your app.js?